# How to set field value of CompletableFuture object with second ComputableFuture object

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream, completable-future

I have a method like:

```
public CompletableFuture<List<Employee>> handleFutures(CompletableFuture<Factory> factoryCompletableFuture, CompletableFuture<Task> taskCompletableFuture)
      throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
      //logic
}
```

I want to use `CompletableFuture<Task> taskCompletableFuture` to set the value of a field `task` in the `CompletableFuture<Factory> factoryCompletableFuture` object.

Task class looks like:

```
public enum Task {
    MECHANIC,
    ENGINEER
}
```

Employee class looks like:

```
public class Employee {
    private Task task;
}
```

Factory class looks like:

```
public class Factory{
    private Optional<List<Employee>> employees;
}
```

I have a stream like:

```
    Task task = taskCompletableFuture.get();

    List<Employee> collect = factoryCompletableFuture.get().getEmployees().stream()
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .peek(empl -> empl.setTask(task))
        .map(CompletableFuture::completedFuture)
        .map(CompletableFuture::join)
        .collect(toList());
```

which return List of Employee.

All I want to achieve is wrapping in a gentle way above stream with CompletableFuture to get a result as `CompletableFuture<List<Employee>>` and call a method logic like:

```
return factoryCompletableFuture.thenApply(do logic here which will set value and return CompletableFuture).
```

By the way, I know that Optional with a list is not a good practice but I cannot change this. Peek for setter usage is either not the best option but this maneuver doesn't need an additional object to repack the changed object with eventual forEach usage.

I will be grateful for a suggestion on how to reach a desirable goal.

Comment: Besides the use of `Optional<List<Employee>> employees`, which doesn't stand justified. The entities shared in the question would fail to compile the corresponding code(`flatMap` usage).

Comment: @Naman Why you claim that will not work? Can you suggest how to rewrite this code to make it work properly?

Comment: @Naman, I think you are confused by the `getEmployees().stream()` call, which is actually calling the [`Optional.stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#stream--) method, returning a `Stream<List<Employee>>` on which the `flatMap()` will work fine.

Comment: @Martin The two `map()` calls are strange though (`.map(CompletableFuture::completedFuture).map(CompletableFuture::join)`): you are simply boxing your result in a `CompletableFuture`, and immediately unboxing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to use [`thenCombine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#thenCombine-java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage-java.util.function.BiFunction-):

```
public CompletableFuture<List<Employee>> handleFutures(
        CompletableFuture<Factory> factoryCompletableFuture,
        CompletableFuture<Task> taskCompletableFuture) {
    return factoryCompletableFuture.thenCombine(taskCompletableFuture,
        (factory, task) -> factory.getEmployees().stream()
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .peek(empl -> empl.setTask(task))
            .collect(toList()));
}
```